# Does Apache/Calcite support HashMap type of data in terms of storage and query?

Tags: apache-calcite

Let's say we have 10 records as following in a table name "TEST":

Record<"ID":Integer, "Name":String, "MapRelation":HashMap>

Does Calcite support SQL on these records?

For example:

> select MapRelation from TEST where ID = ...

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? Calcite does have support for many nonscalar datatypes such as `MAP`.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to support MAP data type in Apache/Beam, which uses Calcite SQL engine. But I ran into some sqlValidation error, so I was wondering if Calcite supports those non-scalar data types.

Comment: Calcite does support such types. If you're having a specific problem with Beam, I'd suggest you post the code you're using.